# Allow only localhost for iframe

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Running a LAMP environment, I would only like a web visible page available to load if requested by an iframe on the same host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `x-frame-options` header to `sameorigin`. See Mozilla reference for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: this is a cross-browser header specific not just to Firefox ? In a web search for the term it seems like it is.

Comment: I see the browser support at the bottom now. Is something server-sider available ? Whether or not the browser will honor the header may not be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the server variable $_SERVER["remote_address"] (available in all languages) to check the IP visiting the page and display the iframe if it matches 127.0.0.1 por any of the local IPs

Comment: it is possible to spoof IPs, of course. I was thinking of setting the apache `order` directive to something along the lines of `deny, allow` if thats possible

Comment: You can avoid spoofing by allowing only your local host mac adress(es) in iptables like this: /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 80 -m mac --mac-source 00:00:00:91:00:07 -j ACCEPT. MAC addresses can't be spoofed from outside your LAN unless they previously gain access to your LAN and in that case spoofing is the smallest problem that you would have

Comment: I belive iptables would enforce that rule on all directories in the system. I was hoping for just a particular directory.